# Map many to many relationship when join table has its own PK

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, mapping, many-to-many

I have to map a relationship Person with Tasks. OK.
My problem is that I cannot alter the DB and the JOIN table 'Person_Task' has this fields: `PERSON_TASK_ID, PERSON_ID, TASK_ID`
with a sequence for `PERSON_TASK_ID`.

When I insert a new Task I get a beatiful:

`java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("USER"."PERSON_TASK"."PERSON_TASK_ID")`

It would be really nice if someone can help me to accomplish this **without creating a new entity** :)

Comment: Barring some solution at the database level, you will need to create a  new Join entity which is normally recommended anyway as it is likely you will want to store some additional info about the relationship e.g. date_allocated.

Comment: By solution at the database level I am thinking of something like a 'sequence trigger' as outlined in the following which will compensate for the fact that your JPA insert is not going to have the PERSON_TASK_ID: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330305/oracle-trigger-to-create-an-autonumber

Comment: Thanks Alan, Im doing it that way!